# Change image on a button selection

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

i will need some help with some coding if possible. I would like to have when each button is clicked the picture shown to change. I have uploaded a picture how i would like to have the buttons and the picture positioned, also to be responsive on mobile (buttons below, picture above).

I have also uploaded the code i am using at the moment. Thank you very much for the time spent!

```css
  * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.imagebox {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
}

.imagebox img {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
}

.textbox-cont {
  width: 50%;
  height: 300px;
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.textbox {
  color: #000000;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  .imagebox,
  .textbox-cont {
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
  }
```

```html
<div class="imagebox" class="col-lg-12 scrollReveal sr-bottom sr-ease-in-out-quad sr-delay-1">
  <img src="http://cdns2.freepik.com/free-photo/twitter-logo_318-40459.jpg" width="400px" heigh="358px" />
</div>
<div class="textbox-cont">
  <div class="textbox">
    <p style="margin">Pick a Color Scheme</p>
    <p></p>
    <div></div>
    <a href="#">Read More</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: "col-lg-12' looks like a Bootstrap style. Are you using Bootstrap?

Comment: yes i am using bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

Add your desired buttons inside the html section, then attach onclick listeners to handle when the button is clicked. I think the cleanest way to do this would be to give your buttons individual ids, and then add event listeners in a js file.
For example, to change the image (give id="img") with the click of button that has id "button":

```
const img = document.getElementById('img');
const button = document.getElementById('button');
button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    img.src = "add-img-src-here"
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to add some of HTML code with jQuery in the HTML:

1. `<img src='' id='image_1' alt='There is a problem'>`
2. `<button id='but_1'></button>`

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#but_1').click(function(){
        $('#image_url').attr('src','url');
    });
});
```

Or, you can use this code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
        $("button").click(function(){
          $("img").attr("src", "url");
        });
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>

    <img src="" alt="there some problem here">

    <button>Click Here To Change Picture</button>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: How do i put several pictures with different id's? Didn not quite get that. Thank you for your time!

Comment: (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62392639/change-image-on-a-button-selection#answer-62517268)

Answer (score 0):

yes you can use specific id to change any property .Ok
again you can use this code good luck.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
          <head>
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script>

              $(document).ready(function(){
                var id = '';
                $("img").click(function(){
                  id = $(this).attr('id');
                  src = $(this).attr('src');
                  alert("id: "+id+" src: "+ src);
                  $("#"+id).attr("src", "url");
                  $("#"+id).attr("alt", "Changed");
                });
              });
            </script>
          </head>
          <body>
            <div class="container">
<h1>Just Click On Image </h1>
      <table class="table table-hover">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>image</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td><img src="class.png" alt="There Is Some Problem Here"id="img-1"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><img src="class.png" alt="There Is Some Problem Here"id="img-2"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><img src="class.png" alt="There Is Some Problem Here"id="img-3"></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
          </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: Which one of your answers is the correct one according you?